# How to add an empty unnumbered page to the end of a document?

Tags: lastpage, emptypage

I would like to add an empty (double) page to the end of a document, which is not counted by commands like `\pageref{LastPage}`. If you want so, one could say the printer should add an empty page.

`\clearpage` seems to work for a single page (not accounting for even/odd to make sure it is not a backside), but doesn't prevent the `\pagestyle{myheadings}` header. I guess removing the header would work by changing the pagestyle on the last page, but still the numbering `page X of LastPage` on the other pages would be off.

Comment: Before trying to answer your  question, let me ask, why do you want this? What is the actual use case?

Comment: I want to attach an empty page to an exam. At the moment I just added a page with `\newpage\null` and a macro that adds another one when it's odd, but it both does not require a number and could be reused when the student did not need the page. By adding the page to the PDF, I do not need to attach the additional page manually. I guess one alternative would be to add an empty page with a tool like `pdftk`, but it would be cleaner to do this with pure LaTeX.

Answer (score 4):

This here creates three pages where LastPage reports two:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\AddToHook{enddocument}{\newpage\mbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}}
\begin{document}
\pageref{LastPage}
abc
\newpage
blub

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I add an answer with my check for an odd page.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Ulrike Fischer's answer, this solution adds one or two empty pages depending on if the document ends with an odd page.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{changepage}

\AddToHook{enddocument}{
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \checkoddpage
    \ifoddpage \else \newpage\null \fi
    \newpage\null
    \thispagestyle{empty}
}
\begin{document}
\pageref{LastPage}
abc
\newpage
blub
\newpage
foo

\end{document}
```

The check for an odd page makes sure, that the blank page is not a backside, which would not add a blank page when printing two-sided.